# Как  скопировать часть строки от определенного символа и до конца этой строки?

Tags: строки, c++

Cуть моeй проблемы следующая. Есть масив типа `char` где хранятся строки (знак конца строки конечно есть). У меня есть номер смивола (допустип 100). Как мне от этого символа скопировать строку до конца? Притом так надо сделать несколько раз, то есть  нужно скопировать несколько строк из одного массива.

P.s. В голове, конечно, есть замысел, но он крайне не рационален и сложен, поэтому решил спросить у профи)

Comment: Ваше описание данных можно понять двояко. Лучше кусочек кода с описанием данных приведите (откуда и куда копировать) и может быть код, заполняющий источник.

Comment: >Есть масив типа char где хранятся строки

Так в этом массиве хранится несколько строк или одна строка? По моим соображениям, в массиве типа char должна храниться одна строка

>У меня есть номер смивола (допустип 100). 

100 - это порядковый номер элемента в массиве или его числовое значение?

Comment: Вы представляете чего только в этой голове нету ?!)) например "масив типа char где хранятся строки", кроме этого "знак конца строки есть", плюс ко всему "есть номер смивола" Притом так "скопировать строку до конца надо сделать несколько раз", почему только меня одного, во истину сопливого ламера смутил этот пост, почему гуру отвечают в духе "можно я, можно я, можно я отвечу", знаете Друзья, это выглядит низко такое чувство что все готовы смешать с грязью тех кто не знает каких то нюансов и они же целуют в попку чайничков) Лично я не против, но н** так жить ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Толком ничего не понял, что вам требуется, но, кажется, догадываюсь. Может, вы имеете ввиду "обрезание" строки от нужной позиции до конца? Кто знает...

```
char *str = "C++ is a statically typed, free-form, multi-paradigm, compiled, general-purpose programming language.";

std::string mod_s(str);
std::string::size_type pos = mod_s.find("typed");
if(pos!=string::npos)
{
std::string new_mod_s(mod_s.substr(pos));
std::cout<<new_mod_s<<std::endl;
}
system("Pause");
```

Comment: - У вас течет память, поскольку `str = "..."` присваивает указатель, а прошлый указатель остается висеть неосвобожденным.

- Почему не просто `std::string mod_s("C++ is a statically typed, free-form, ...")`?

- Если `pos` в результате будет равен `string::npos,` то ваш код выбросит `std::out_of_range,` что не очень здорово.

Comment: Спасибо, @Котик_хочет_кушать, память и правда текла, текла потому, что раньше между первой и второй строчкой был код, который работал с указателем, потом его освобождал. Я не заметил, что выделение то идет, а память потом нигде не освобождается. А что касается второго пункта, так это то, что здесь такие мелочи уже должен просчитывать сам автор вопроса, а не я. Но я все же поправлю, раз это так режет глаз =). Благодарю.

Comment: Забавно выглядят комментарии и **измененному** коду.

Comment: @gen1321, а где же здесь **строки** (во множественном числе) о которых Вы говорили в вопросе?

Здесь **ОДНА строка**. Если это то, что Вы хотели, то (IMHO) обратите внимание на ответ @lirik90, как наиболее прозрачный.

Answer (score 7):

> Как скопировать часть строки от определенного символа и до конца этой строки?

```
char str[] = "строка: Hello world", buffer[64];

strcpy(buffer, &str[8]);

printf(buffer); //Hello world
```

Comment: Именно так

Answer (score 5):

Еще вариант решения с использованием итераторов:

```
char const* str = "In short, we chose quality over quantity. Some boost libraries could also be candidates for inclusion though. While their tutorials are very good, the reference documentation is often very inflexible and inconvenient.";

//т.к. простой указатель - это тоже итератор, то можно сделать так:
size_t str_length = strlen(str);
std::string trimmed( str + 100, //Смещаемся на 100 символов вперед от начала строки        
                     str + str_length); //Итератор конца: указывает на элемент, следующий за последним символом строки
```

Тогда объект `trimmed` будет содержать все элементы `str` от 100 символа и до конца.

Answer (score 5):

Толком понять не удалось, но допустим...

Мы прочли **текстовый** файл в буфер (и завершили его символом `'\0'`). Тогда с т.з. Си (С++) у нас есть тот самый массив символов со строками, завершающимися символом `'\n'`.

Вот такая функция копирует символы из буфера с заданной позиции до символа `'\n'` (включая его) или до конца буфера в строковый массив (dst), который всегда завершается нулем.
 Возвращает количество скопированных байт.

```
int
get_line (char *dst, int limit, char *src, int pos)
{
  char *s = dst, *end = dst+limit-1;

  src += pos;
  while ((dst < end) && (*dst = *src++))
    if (*dst++ == '\n')
      break;
  *dst = 0;

  return dst-s;
}
```

Несколько напоминает fgets() :)

Собственно, ее можно сделать еще более похожей, на известную fgets()

```
int get_line (char *dst, int limit, char *src);
```

и тогда вызывать не

```
char line[100];
...
get_line(line,sizeof(line),buf,pos);
```

а

```
get_line(line,sizeof(line),buf+pos); // IMHO так красивей
```

или

```
get_line(line,sizeof(line),&buf[pos]); // то же самое, но может Вам привычней...
```

[[@gen1321](/users/8858/gen1321)](/users/8858/gen1321), это то о чем Вы спрашивали?

Answer (score 4):

```
strcpy(str2, str1+100);
```

Не забудь выделить достаточное количество памяти для str2. Оно равно strlen(str1+100)+1, либо можно создать массив на стеке большого размера, в который поместится любая строка.

Answer (score 2):

Решение в стиле C строк и указателей. Используйте memset. Вот скажем пример который копирует в tag имя файла без расширения

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
   char *Name= "YetAnotherWin32TrojanHorse.exe"; //Инициализируем входную строку(Name)
   char *tag= new char[strlen(Name)-4]; //Запрашиваем кучу для хранения выхода (Tag)
   memset(tag,0, sizeof(tag)/sizeof(tag[0])); //Инициализируем выход, заполняя нулями
   strncat(tag,Name,strlen(Name)-4); //Конкатенация tag ="YetAnotherWin32TrojanHorse" 
}
```

Если хотите обрезать с начала символы просто занулите их через memset. Если хотите вырезать подстроку то просто добавьте нужное число к указателю и он станет указывать на нужную букву.

Comment: А зачем memset()? Одного нолика в *нужное место* недостаточно?

Comment: @avp Если честно понятия не имею, думайте сработает? Проверю на досуге.

Answer (score 2):

У класса string есть метод append, которому нужно передать указатель на начало строки и он сам все скопирует до конца. пример

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char t[] = "123456";
  string s;
  s.append(&t[2]);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Неужели автор спрашивал *это*? 

IMHO он упоминал о неких символах, завершающих СТРОК**И** в массиве.

Comment: А мне кажется что он говорил о '\n' ...

Answer (score 1):

```
  void strcopy(char* main, char* second, int pos, int k)
{
    if (pos > strlen(main))
    {
        second[0] = 0;
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < k; ++i)
    {
        second[i] = main[pos++];
    }
    second[i] = 0;
}
```